# How can I use response message from google tv to smart phone

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm developer from korea. I have one question, so enter this site.
The problem is that using the response message from google tv to smart phone.
I want send the question from google tv to smart phone, the question show in google tv 
and reply in smart phone.
at that time, how can I send message from google tv to smart phone?
To use anymote library? or call any method?

If you know my question, please reply it.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much latency you desire.  You could use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to send from the TV -> phone.  On the other hand, you could also listen on a socket when the app you wish to signal is open and send from the TV to the phone.  This, of course, will potentially use substantially more power.

Comment: I already use anymotelibrary in smart phone. It used second-screen app with google tv. so I can't use cloud messaging. May be It must use com.google.anymote.server.ServerAdapter with socket. I want to know about it.

Comment: Sir, How to listen on a socket in google tv? Is it use anymote library like ServerAdapter?

Comment: Please, give me a reference code using anymote library. I want to know that as soon as possible.

Comment: Use standard android mechanisms.  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/  It's not a part of AnyMote.